# SQL-Server Recursive Query

Tags: sql-server

I have some data that resides in a table that I can easily select from and I need to calculate an output value for each row based on the previous row's value, with the exception of the first row, which is calculated using a value I calculate in the select query initially.  I have tried multiple iterations of the recursive code and utilizing CTEs but I have been unsuccessful in getting it to work.  I am driving myself insane trying to get it working and I would rather not run a loop because it takes to long to complete.  We are running sql server 2012 and I am writing the code in SSMS 2014.

```
select 1 as rn, 1.5 x1, 2.5 x2, 2.0 x3, 45 y1, 42 y2, 43 ild into #x
union all
select 2 as rn, 1.7 x1, 2.2 x2, 2.1 x3, 55 y1, 12 y2, 43 ild
```

the code to calculate the first row is

```
select x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * ild from #x where rn = 1
```

the code to calculate the second row through n row is

```
select x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * (previous row's calculated value)
```

please let me know if there is something I am missing because I have 8760 rows of data that I need to roll through 57 times (each is a different data set) and doing the loop isn't fast enough for what I need it for.

Comment: Use LAG/LEAD? That may be easier than the recursive cte

Comment: If I am using lag, wouldn't that cause me to have 8759 imbedded calculations by the end of the query?  Meaning, row 2 is dependent on the calculated result of row 1, row 3 is dependent on the calculated result of row 2, which is dependent on the calculated result of row 1.  So row 3 would be something like
    `code` select x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * (x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * (x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * ild)) `code`
where the x values inside the first parenthesis belong to the row it was calculated from

Comment: A procedure with a cursor and a for loop is probably a good method for such a cascaded calculation.

Comment: That is how I currently  have it coded but it takes 8 minutes to complete the calculation.  i was hoping to find a faster solution without going to a separate compiled language.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but there's a big difference between x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * ild and ( x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3) * ild, Which is the intended order of operations?  For the first row is the expected answer 258.5 or 7503.5?

Comment: @LukStorms a cursor is the slowest way possible to calculate anything in an RDBMS. It *is* possible to use windowing functions, self joins etc to execute the same query a lot faster

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott don't assume about LEAD/LAG, try it. The server knows what these mean and can optimize them.

Comment: I don't know how to make the lag function work or I would try it. My mind is getting stuck on the fact that the second row needs to use the first row's calculated value and the 3rd row needs to use the second row's calculated value (which is using the first row's calculated value) and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a recursive cte, but I can't speak to the performance of 87,000 rows

```
;with cte as (
    Select rn  ,Calc = cast( x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3 * ild as money)  from #x Where rn=1
    Union All
    Select r.rn,cast(r.x1*r.y1 + r.x2*r.y2 + r.x3 * p.Calc as money)
    From  #x r
    Join  cte p on r.rn=p.rn+1
)
Select * from cte
Option (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Returns

```
rn  Calc
1   258.50
2   662.75
```

**I should note: I'm assuming RN is incremental with no gaps**

Comment: lol, posted almost the same answer, didn't get a toast like I normally do when there is another answer posted. removed mine.

Comment: Windowing functions, LAG, LEAD etc are usually a lot faster than a CTE, because the server understands them and can optimize them.

Comment: @RuslanK. I suspect you duplicated a RN?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 100% agreement, that was my first thought, however, I got stuck on the cascade

Comment: @John Cappelletti, thank you for the code. While it did answer the question, which I will give you credit for, the overall performance for the dataset is still pretty much the same. I will try to research more on the lag option to see if I can speed this up any with that.

Comment: @John Cappelletti, it takes 6 seconds to calculate. And right now, no, the rn does not have an index.  Right now I am loading the query results into #x and then operating on that. Would I gain a performance boost if I loaded it into a declared table, @x, added an index to the rn and operate off that table?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott A temp with an index would be better than a table variable.   Recursive ctes are great but not known for performance on bigger data.  For example, I can build a 200K hierarchy in 7 seconds, but the cte approach is over 5 minutes.

Comment: @John Cappelletti, thank you for the reminder. The calc time is now 6 seconds total for everything, down from 21.

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott Better, but not fabulous.  I'll noodle it a bit more.  After all, I really don't want to rake leaves.